# error: cast from 'const prog_uchar*' to 'byte' loses precision?

Tags: c++, c, avr

The error is at this line :

```
dataArray[iLedMatrix][iRow] |=  (byte)(bufferPattern[iRow]) & (1<<7);
```

**dataArray** is : byte dataArray[NUMBER_LED_MATRIX][NUMBER_ROW_PER_MATRIX];

**bufferPattern** is : const patternp * bufferPattern;

**patternp** is a typedef of the type : typedef prog_uchar patternp[NUM_ROWS];

I can see in the Reference that prog_uchar is 1 byte ( 0 to 255 ). So I do not understand the error about losing precision? Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this sub expression

```
(byte)(bufferPattern[iRow])
```

The variable bufferPattern is of type `const patternp *` so when the indexer is applied the result is patternp.  The type "patternp" is typedef to prog_uchar[].  So in actuality this expression is saying

> Cast a prog_uchar* to a byte

Byte is almost certainly a single byte value and prog_uchar* is the platform specific pointer type (either 4 or 8 bytes).  This does indeed result in a loss of precision.  Perhaps you meant to dereferenc this value?

```
(byte)(*(bufferPattern[iRow]))
```

Comment: You got the problem and the right solution. Thx, my C is a little rusty, I need to wake up! Thx

Comment: Incidentally, as the platform is AVR - pointers are only 16bits.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to cast from a pointer type to byte. A pointer type is usually represented on 4 bytes (32 bit OS) or 8 bytes (64 bits), and you are trying to convert its address value to 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks, cannot accept because you are right about the reason but Jared got the reason and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`bufferPattern[ iRow ]` resolves to a `patternp`, which is a `prog_uchar[ NUM_ROWS ]`.

So you're actually casting an array (implemented as a pointer) to a byte.  Makes no sense; lucky the compiler warned you!